# change all links in my website to https

Tags: javascript, http, https

My site in blogger with the domain https://www.arwikig.com/
As you see I use ssl, and every think is good but in the posts I see the error "same things not save in this site" and I see in my site too many links in my site use http .. Even though in my html all links are '//' it mean https .. & I try to use this js.

```
        <script type='text/javascript'>
    //<![CDATA[
    function RedirNonHttps() {
        if (location.href.indexOf("https://") == -1) {
            location.href = location.href.replace("http://", "https://");
        }
    }
    //]]>
    </script>
```

& too much other scriptes like this & I dont see any effects
thanks for help me & I'm sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I guess you executed the function right? if you didn't you can make it automatically doing this:

```
<!--This awesome script -->
<script type='text/javascript'>
    //<![CDATA[
        (function RedirNonHttps() {
            if (location.href.indexOf("https://") == -1) 
            {
                location.href = location.href.replace("http://", "https://");
            }
         })();
    //]]>
</script>
```

This syntax is known as "Self invoking function", there's [a link](https://sarfraznawaz.wordpress.com/2012/01/26/javascript-self-invoking-functions/)

**UPDATE #1**
Well, I was testing this code in your website, to change the `'http'` in each `href`, `src` or `content` attributes.

```
// 1. let's find those bad guys who are annoying us
// [href*='http:']    => Will find those with attribute href containing the string http
// [src*='http:']     => Will find those with attribute src containing the string http
// [content*='http:'] => Will find those with attribute content containing the string http

$("[href*='http:'], [src*='http:'], [content*='http:']").each(function(){

   // Let's save the reference of matched item
          var element = $(this);

   // 2. Get the attributes for the current matched element, it could has href, 
   // src or even content attributes, and finally replace them
          var href    = (element.attr("href")    || "").replace("http://", "https://");
          var src     = (element.attr("src")     || "").replace("http://", "https://");
          var content = (element.attr("content") || "").replace("http://", "https://");

   // 3. Now just update the new attributes with the fresh and sweet data
          element.attr("href"   , href);
          element.attr("src"    , src);
          element.attr("content", content);
});
```

Hope it helped you. But I still considering that you should write manually this in your code.

Oh, by the way! To call it, you should wrap it in a `$(document).ready()` or `$(function(){})`, because jQuery needs that the whole page be full loaded to works:

```
// Common way... 
$(document).ready(function(){
    // - - The code that I wrote before
});

// Or you can use this way! (Pretty short and funny)
$(function(){
    // - - The code that I wrote before
});
```

Comment: ty .. I  try this but not working .. I'm not know why

Comment: But bro, you should try to explain a little more your question. For example, how do you call the function... Is it called in a link onclick event ?

Comment: I'm not good with scripts but I want any way will change all sites in my site to https & ty for reply ^^

Comment: So let me see if I got the idea of your problem.
You have many links with `http` protocol and you want to change then with `https` ?

Comment: yes that is my proplem but I see this links with http in view-source:https://www.arwikig.com/
& in my html editor all links with https

Comment: Oh well, that's more info ^-^... Well I checked the view-source of your site and you're right there are links with `http`, but `https` in links. 

But also, the `<link>` tags still have the `http` so, the secure server doesn't import or make the request for those resources because the come from a "_no secure_" source. Maybe you have to change the href attribute in those tags by yourself in the code.

Comment: ty pro secend scripte is works Amazing & change all links to https .. but only another Something small .. can you see my view-source again .. same links like http://www.arwikig.com/favicon.ico .. is use " http " .. my hosting is blogger & I don't see that links in page html .. can I do any think for change it to https too ?

Comment: I think I know same think .. I use expressions like 
<link expr:href='data:blog.homepageUrl' rel='openid.delegate'/>
 data:blog.homepageUrl will mean http://‌​www.arwikig.com .. .. I try that 
<link expr:href='&quot;https://&quot; + data:blog.homepageUrl' rel='openid.delegate'/> 
but that mean https://‌​http://‌​www.arwikig.com .. can you help me to fix that please

Comment: Hi, did it work? •O• ... mmm I didn't see any link with `http` after you run the script. But I found that you have a kind of "widget" plugin (well I don't know too much) that has many links in `http`, but this case is different. 

For that, you should change them manually.